# Ionic beautify js file back

Tags: ionic-framework

I have received one project from my senior and it is uglified. There is no official documentation as well and when I try to check svn, there is only one version (uglified one). I see variable name like e, t, o, r.

[image]

I am also just beginner in ionic.

How shall I do? Is there a way that I can beautify back or do I really need to chase them down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [beautify](http://jsbeautifier.org/) the project but that would be just one big mess of "beautified" code. This would be one js file that may be already transpiled down from ES6 or Typescript, that contains all the "rendered" templates and all the application logic along with all the Ionic truckloads of code plus of course all the Cordova code.

**=**

**CHASE THAT mother... DOWN and save yourself from this madness!**

Unless this is a job post on reverse engineering, in which case go on.

Comment: I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. Can I also re-map those alphabet to meaningful variable?

Comment: Nope! :/ And even if you could, we are talking about a single monolithic multimegabyte sized file here. Honestly it's not even worh thinking about it. Just get the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will do that. :)